# Text box inside a grid view not showing data

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am adding a text box inside a grid view.

When a user clicks the add button a new text box is created.

I am getting all data from text boxes, but when I add data the text boxes are showing nothing

```
          private void SetPreviousTids(DataTable dt)
          {
             if (ViewState["TidTable"] != null)
               {
                  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                  {
                 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

               TextBox Tid =  (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Tid");
               Response.Write(Tid.Text.ToString());
               Tid.Text = "hello";// text not showing on text box
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

ASPX code here

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="+" OnClick="Add_Tid" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You should put your SetPreviousTids code inside the gridview_RowDataBound handler and access the control using RowEventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)(e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("Tid"));
        myTextBox.Text == "hello";
    }
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to show more code if you need help debugging. You can't just access the row bound controls from anywhere in your code behind. You need to use the grid specific handlers for that.

Comment: but i am accessing value but value is not showing this is my simple function which i call from on page load every time i call function to rad text box values and want to show but value is not showing

Comment: is there any way to show value out side the grid view functions?

Comment: You may be able to use some javascript to access the textbox values once the grid is loaded. If you want to do it from the code behind you'll need to follow the above example.

Answer (score 0):

When using Templates such as `<asp:TemplateField>` to define a column for GridView, such Columns can't be accessed using `Cells` property.

However when using bound fields `<asp:BoundField .. />` to define Columns for GridView you can use the `Cells` property to access columns.

So, Change

```
TextBox Tid =  (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Tid");
```

to

```
TextBox Tid =  (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Tid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work!

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdList" runat="server" Visible="true" onrowcommand="grdList_RowCommandEvent">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Tid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TextboxInfor") >%'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="+" CommandName="AddNew" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And Code behind should look like:

```
namespace Demo
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataTable _tableData;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                _tableData=new DataTable();
                _tableData.Columns.Add("TextboxInfor");
                ViewState["TidTable"]=_tableData;
            }
        }       
        protected void grdList_RowCommandEvent(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.CommandName.Equlas("AddNew"))
            {   
                _tableData= ViewState["TidTable"] as DataTable;         
                for (int i = 0; i < grdList.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var Tid= gvMandiStatistics.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("Tid") as TextBox;
                    _tableData.Rows[i]["TextboxInfor"]=Tid.Text;
                }               
                var dr= _tableData.NewRow();
                dr["TextboxInfor"]=string.Empty;
                _tableData.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }       
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            _tableData= ViewState["TidTable"] as DataTable; 
            grdList.DataSource=_tableData;
            grdList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Forgive if there are some typo mistakes as entire code is written in **NOTEPAD :D**